# vscode cortex-debug halt stm32

Tags: visual-studio-code, stm32, vscode-debugger, cortex-m

Hi i wanted to know if there was anyway to stop the program halting when i attach to stm32

launch.json

```
{
  "name": "Attach STM32 STLink",
  "showDevDebugOutput": "parsed",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "executable": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
  "request": "attach",
  "type": "cortex-debug",
  "servertype": "stlink",
  "device": "STM32G030F6PX",
  "svdFile": "${command:vscode-embedded.st.svd}/STM32G030.svd",
  "v1": false,
  "breakAfterReset": false,
}
```

This is what it shows in the debug console

```
Setting GDB-Server CWD: C:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.14.0\STM32CubeIDE\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.stlink-gdb-server.win32_2.1.100.202310302101\tools\bin
Launching gdb-server: "C:\\ST\\STM32CubeIDE_1.14.0\\STM32CubeIDE\\plugins\\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.stlink-gdb-server.win32_2.1.100.202310302101\\tools\\bin\\ST-LINK_gdbserver.exe" -p 50000 -cp "C:\\ST\\STM32CubeIDE_1.14.0\\STM32CubeIDE\\plugins\\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.cubeprogrammer.win32_2.1.100.202311100844\\tools\\bin" --swd --attach --halt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding postAttachCommands or postLaunchCommands in your launch.json.

You can find cortex-debug attributes listed and explained [in this link](https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug/blob/master/debug_attributes.md).

Following should work:

```
{
  "name": "Attach STM32 STLink",
  "showDevDebugOutput": "parsed",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "executable": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
  "request": "attach",
  "type": "cortex-debug",
  "servertype": "stlink",
  "device": "STM32G030F6PX",
  "svdFile": "${command:vscode-embedded.st.svd}/STM32G030.svd",
  "v1": false,
  "breakAfterReset": false,
  "postAttachCommands" : ["continue"]
}
```